# Curl force to Timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout, connection-timeout

I am trying to test my timeout conditions using curl and force the website to timeout. Here is my curl settings:

```html
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.sample.com/api/abc/changelogs?last=3",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
 "cache-control: no-cache"
 ),
));
```

Eventhough I changed the CONNECTTIMEOUT and TIMEOUT into 0 / 0.000001 it still wont time out. Any help would be nice.

Comment: No wonder, since `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` is an `int`...

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) explains that 0 is like no timeout, and @AlexKarshin explained that it's an integer. So try to set it to 1.

Comment: @AlexKarshin Then is there a way to force the time out while using an int since I have to start from 1.

Comment: @AnthonyB if i set it to 1, it wont trigger a timeout

Comment: @SnowBut It's because this value is an integer in seconds. But Alex's anwser explains that you can use an other value in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` is an integer:

> The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

If you have cURL >= 7.16.2 and PHP >= 5.2.3, you may use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`:

> The number of milliseconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely. If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the connect will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second.

Though, you should not confuse it with `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`:

> **`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`** - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
>   **`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`** - The maximum number of milliseconds to allow cURL functions to execute. If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the connect will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second.

The obvious difference being that `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` is timeout before script dies if no connection is present; whilst `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` kills the script after defined number of seconds.

Comment: Great! A code sample directly reproducible would be great.

Comment: @AnthonyB I'm not sure... Should I take OP's code and simply change `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,` to `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 1,`? Feels degrading to me. Surely OP can do it himself.

Comment: I finally understand, thank you for you help @AnthonyB

Comment: @AlexKarshin Thank you for you help :)

Comment: @AlexKarshin In [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is it said `but it should also include “try this instead"` so even if it is a little example it could be useful. According to me a little example using the right option could be good, but is not mandatory.